# Vertical Partitioning in Scalding

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, scalding, data-partitioning

I have a `TypedTipe[(String, String, Long)]` where the first String can assume only a limited (~10) number of values. I'd like to partition my output so that a folder is created for each type (I.E. 10 folders with the name of the first String). This is simple to achieve in Hive, however I cannot find an elegant way to do it in Scalding. The method `def partition(p: T => Boolean): (TypedPipe[T], TypedPipe[T])` breaks the pipe in 2 parts but does not do what I'm looking for.

**EDIT**

- I am using Scalding `v0.13.1`
- I need to write a `PackedAvroSource`

Answer (score 1):

If you group by the field you want to partition by, you can then use [PartitionedDelimitedSource](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/develop/scalding-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/scalding/typed/PartitionedDelimitedSource.scala) to write the directory structure as needed. Ex:

```
val pipe: TypedPipe[(String, String, Long)] = ...
pipe
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .write(PartitionedDelimited[String, (String, String, Long)](args("output"), "%s"))
```

Comment: My `Grouped[K, (String, String, Long)]` does not let me 'write'... Could this be a version issue? Also, is there a way to write a `PackedAvroSource` with the same technique?

Comment: I also can't find `PartitionedDelimited` in my classpath. There is `PartitionedDelimitedSource` but it takes more arguments.